# Angular SignalR HubConnection gives 'Protocol error: Unknown transport.'

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api, signalr, angular-cli

I have an Owin-selfhosted API running on http://localhost:8090/.
I created a signalR hub with the following code:

```
app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll); //Inside Startup.cs
app.MapSignalR(); //Inside Startup.cs

//Inside own class file
public class SensorHub: Hub
{
    public void Send(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Send called with message argument: {0}", message);
        Clients.All.addMessage(message);
    }
}
```

I also made another C# client to test my signalR hub and I get responses from the hub so I suppose it's functional and working well. See following code:

```
//My working C# client
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 10;
    var url = "http://localhost:8090/signalr";
    var hub = new HubConnection(url);

    var proxy = hub.CreateHubProxy("SensorHub");
    proxy.On("addMessage", message => Console.WriteLine("Data received: " + message));

    // Start hub connection
    Console.WriteLine("Starting hub connection at: {0}", url);
    hub.Start().Wait();
    Console.WriteLine("Hub connected with transport: {0}", hub.Transport.Name);

    // Call hub
    var list = new List<string>
    {
        "value1",
        "value2",
        "value3"
    };

    foreach (var value in list)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sending data to hub connection: {0}", value);
        proxy.Invoke("Send", value);
    }

    Console.Read();
}
```

I want to establish a connection with my backend-sensorhub and my angular website. I installed the `@aspnet/signalr-client` package. Below my angular code:

```
//My failing angular client
ngOnInit() {
    let connection = new HubConnection('http://localhost:8090/signalr/sensorhub');

    connection.on('addMessage', data => {
      console.log(data);
    });

    connection.start().then(() => console.log('started'));
}
```

Once I get past the `connection.Start()` line I get a '400 Bad Request error' containg the following message: **Protocol error: Unknown transport.**

Note: I don't use .NET Core!
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem comes from the facts that the `@aspnet/signalr-client` package is build for ASP.NET Core.

Therefore I ended up using another yarn package called `ngx-signalr-hubservice`.
It's pretty well documented and worked (almost) out of the box.

Try it out at: https://github.com/steveadoo32/ngx-signalr-hubservice

Comment: how to pass query string with that package?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the angular client is saying that he don't find a hub on the provider url.

Try map the signalr hub on the api, like that...

Startup.cs

```
 app.UseSignalR(routes =>
 {
      routes.MapHub<SensorHub>("sensorhub");
 });
```

And on the clients, try to remove the 'SignalR' from the url path. I don't have much shore about that, but I always use the base uri.

```
ngOnInit() {
    let connection = new HubConnection('http://localhost:8090/sensorhub'); //without the path signalr

    connection.on('addMessage', data => {
      console.log(data);
    });

    connection.start().then(() => console.log('started'));
}
```

Comment: I don't have the `UseSignalR` on my `IAppBuilder`. I think that's part of .NET Core isn't it?

Comment: Also when I mess around with the url it changes from HTTP Error 400 to a 404. So I guess angular can find my hub, it's just not using the right protocol but I have no information how to change that. I guess I will try another angular-package to access my hub.